# Android app using React-native and database storage

Tags: android, database, react-native, crud

I am trying to learn react-native. For now, I am want to save some simple data of my android application in a database. On the Internet I have only found samples for iOs. Is there anyone knowing a tutorial for my purpose and is willing to share? Even some samples of how to open a database or making some CRUD operations, would help me.

Comment: You can try realm for db: https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Realm or Sqlite wrapper libraries. From what i saw realm is more recent, advanced and faster in many aspects.

Sample Operations in realm looks like this

```
const Realm = require('realm');

class Person {}
Person.schema = {
    name: 'Person',
    primaryKey: 'name',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        age: {type: 'int', default: 0},
    },
};

const realm = new Realm({schema: [Person]});

// Query
let people = realm.objects('Person', 'age >= 17');
people.length // => 0

// Write
realm.write(() => {
    savedPerson = realm.create('Person', {
        name: 'Hal Incandenza',
        age: 17,
    });
});

// Queries are updated in real-time
people.length // => 1
```

You can refer this [realm site](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/) for more details

If you prefer using SQLite for database operations u can look into this libraries.

[React Native Sqlite Storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) [ios and android]